Outage in half of house
The ceiling lights are out in half of the hallway, the outlets still work however. My laundry room lights are also out but the dryer turns on however it's not heating up if that matters. I checked the fuse box and nothing is blown....

If in North America, one of your main hots is gone.  Call your power company now to check the outside wires.
Your system uses two hots and a neutral from the pole outside to the meter.
Each hot/live powers one half side of your panel.  The breakers receive power from one half, so all the breakers on one side are getting power.
Going down most panels the two hot sides switch, so first and third breaker on one has power, but the second and forth do not.

I am in north america...will I need an electrician or will the power company come amd fix it

The power company owns the wires to the meter, which they fix for free.  There is a small possibitily that it is the wires from the meter to the panel which  cost you, but they are usually more protected.You need to call the power company first, because it might be dangerous with a loose/broken hot.

Clarifying point about "half" your panel: North American electric panels alternate which hot is used every breaker on a side. That's why the 240V breakers that use two slots are the way they are. They're touching both hots. So when you lose a hot from the power company you're going to lose every other breaker on each side, and any 240V circuits are going to be at half voltage. There's also fun stuff with the 240V appliances bridging the hots and giving low power on the other breakers whenever the appliance is running, but that's usually situational.
